# jenkins build overview page not showing stages in webui

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm using the image: jenkinsci/blueocean from Dockerhub

The build overview page isn't showing the stages of a build.  i.e. the square boxes that represent the stages are not appearing.

Am I missing a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Added a pipeline-stage-view plugin